# Conditional Statment in imagemap hotspot?

Tags: python, renpy

Is that even possible? I want to jump to a label when a particular hotspot on an imagemap is clicked only if pt = 1

pt is defined in the script with a default, I assume that's the best/only way to define a number.

```
screen plane_seat():
imagemap:
    ground "plane.png"
    hotspot(165, 800, 155, 221)
    if pt == 1:
         jump pbathroom_event
    else pass
```

But the error I get is:

**u'jump' is not a keyword argument or valid child for the imagemap statement.**

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly if anyone's curious.

```
hotspot(165, 800, 155, 221) clicked If(pt == 1, Return("pbathroom_event"))
```